# directx local space coordinates float accuracy

Tags: graphics, directx

I'm a bit confused of the local space coordinate system. Suppose I have a complex object in the local space. I know when I want to put it in the world space I have to multiply it with Scale,Rotate,Translate matrix. But the problem is the local coordinate only ranged from -1.0f to 1.0f, when I want to have vertex like (1/500,1/100,1/100) things will not work, everything will become 0 due to the float accuracy problem.
The only solution to me now is separate them into lots of local space systems and ProjectView each individually to put them together. It seems not the correct way of solving the problem. I've been checked lots of books but none of them mentioned this issue. I really want to know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I want to have vertex like (1/500,1/100,1/100) things will not work

What makes you think that? The float accuracy problem does not mean something will coerce to 0 if it can't be accurately represented. It just means, it will coerce to the floating point number closest to the intended figure.

It's the very same as writing down, e.g., 3/9 with at most 6 significant decimal digits: 0.33334 – it didn't coerce to 0. And the very same goes for floating point.

Now you may be familiar with scientific notation: `x·10^y` – this is essentially decimal floating point, a mantissa `x` and an exponent `y` which essentially specifies the order of magnitude. In binary floating point it becomes `x·2^y`. In either case the significant digits are in the mantissa. Your typical floating point number (in OpenGL) has a mantissa of 23 bits, which boils down to an amount of 22 significant binary digits (which are about 7 decimal digits).

> I really want to know how to solve it.

The real trouble with floating point numbers is, if you have to mix and merge numbers over a large range of orders of magnitudes. As long as the numbers are of similar order of magnitudes, everything happens with just the mantissa. And that one last change in order of magnitude to the [-1, 1] range will not hurt you; heck this can be done by "normalizing" the floating point value and then simply *dropping* the exponent.

---

Recommended read: http://floating-point-gui.de/

---

#### Update

One further thing: If you're writing `1/500` in a language like C, then you're performing an *integer division* and that will of course round down to 0. If you want this to be a floating point operation you either have to write floating point literals or cast to float, i.e.

```
1./500.
```

or

```
(float)1/(float)500
```

Note that casting one of the operands to float suffices to make this a *floating point division*.